# WPF ADAL AcquireTokenAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, office365, adal

I'm trying to authenticate my user in a WPF app using ADAL ( Active directory authentication library).

I'm using the following code :

```
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/<my_tenant>.onmicrosoft.com");
AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", "<client_id>",new Uri("<redirect_uri>");
```

The AcquireTokenAsync method need a third parameter : a redirect uri.

I understand the use of this parameter in the case of a web application.

But in the WPF case, I don't understant what to set / how to use it.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

We can set it to the localhost so that the authenticate endpoint can redirect the auth code to client. And it will to request the token using the auth code.

Here is an example for your reference:

```
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourTenant/");
AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net/", "{clientId}", new Uri("http://localhost"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
With your sample, the window for the authentication prompt, but when I type my account and validate, I have the following error :
 AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://localhost' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: <client_id>

Comment: You need to config the `http://localhost` as reply address for the app you register on the Azure portal.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT - I had a similar issue. When I configured application to use localhost, new exception came from ADAL:  `AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'`. But there is no method which accepts both client secret and platform parameters. Can you assist here?

Comment: The code in the post is used for the **public** or **native** client. You were register a web application. Please try to register a new native client.